# in parallel loop, if condition becomes true for multiple threads not one first encountered

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

My subroutine is called by parallel code. I want to write an if statement which is only true for one/first thread who reach it first. then make if section unaccessble for rest of threads.

I use 50 threads however, initialization/first access is countered 10 time, end is never counter sometimes.

!Following is the code. which is part of large parallel code.

```
  if(counter.eq.0) then
     write(*,*) 'initialised'
      !x=0
  endif

  if(counter<totalElement)then
     counter=counter+1
     !equations etc
  endif

  if(counter.eq.totalElement) then
    write(*,*) 'finished'
    counter=0
  endif
```

“I expect the output of

initialized

finished
”

“The output is

initialized

initialized

initialized

initialized

initialized

initialized

initialized

initialized

, but that is wrong because more then one thread found counter zero and initialized.”

!Extra details: parallelization is made on meshed geometry with total numbe rof elements "totalElement".   In serial code i can simply says (if Element=1) initialize and if(Element=totalElement) finishes.

In parallel loops Element is not 1. Code can pick any element for first run. and last loop element is not totalElement. Thats why i made counter variable but still it is not going correct.

Comment: We'll need more to understand how you are doing your parallelism to be able to give you a tailored answer, please see [mcve].  You're probably looking for some form of locking/critical block/atomicity/coherency/etc., but we can't say much more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dear. Actually i am not allowed to share other pieces of code. But is there any technique for letting threads not to accesse if statement to multiple threads and only for first thread.
i have rewritten my question.

Comment: Have you even read [mcve]? You neither need to nor should share your full code, but **craft** an example that shows your issue. Without that, we cannot properly help you.

Comment: well. my subroutine is called with arguments of global variables. i dont have code where parallelization begin. anyways thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code on multi-thread, each thread will do part of the job. Thus, increasing your `counter` through `counter=counter+1` will never allow the variable `counter` to reach the value of `totalElement`. If `counter` is a shared variable, thus you are encontering a race problem. if you are dealing with a shared variable you can protect the access to your variable with atomic clause:

```
     !$omp atomic update 
     counter=counter+1
```

and

```
     !$omp atomic write
     counter=0
```

This should be enough to get rid of thread racing.

If `counter` is a private variable and your schedule is static, then the variable `counter` cannot exceed `totalElement/number_of_used_threads`

More details about your code are welcomed.